# Add new button to Custom Object Lookup dialog box

Tags: lookup, page-layout, search-layout

I have a number of lookup fields on an object.  When I click the magnifying glass to select items from the lookup the Account and Contact object lookup dialogs have a "New" button next to the go.

[image: Account Dialog lookup]

However, for my custom objects, there is no button to create a new record from the dialog box.

[image: Custom Object lookup]

Is there a way to have a new button from there?  Or is there a way to have a custom button OR link on the Add/Edit pages such that I can quick create a record for a lookup on the parent object without leaving the page.

Otherwise, for all of my custom objects people must go to a number of different lookup objects, create the records, then go to the detail object and add all the fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So that "New" button is a feature called "Quick Create" It's an old old old feature.

Right now, it does not support custom objects. You can vote on the idea here: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqPaAAK

something to consider is that Quick Create will ignore any validation rules you have on those objects. Many admins frown upon it's use because it can cause a lot of bad or incomplete data to be created in the system.

Some options you can consider instead of having them go to a different tab to create:

1. Look into creating Quick Actions (Chatter Publisher Actions) to create the records
2. Replace all your pages with visualforce pages so you can create your own version of quick create (Don't do this! Terrible idea but I wanted at least 2 items)

Quick actions are really your best bet but you can't do them from the lookup dialog window. But it would save them from having to leave the record they're viewing.

Comment: So I create a Quick Action using the flow designer?  Or is there a different way to do it?

Comment: you could use Flow... heck that's a neat idea. Use flow called by a button to create the record and then update the record it spawned from.... but a quick action is also called a chatter publisher actions. Those can be found on the Buttons, Links, Actions section of the object. Or there are global actions. They have nothing to do with Flow at all.